# VS Code Python Syntax Highlighting Only Half Working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been using both VS Code and Sublime for a while now. I mostly do my python coding in Sublime and I have recently decided to try out VS Code. One issue though.

The syntax highlighting for python is not functioning in the manner I would expect. Here is a .py file opened in both VS Code and Sublime for comparison:

Sublime Text:
[image: Sublime Text]

VS Code:
[image: Vs Code]

When comparing the VS Code syntax highlighting to that of Sublime, it appears to only function half correctly.

Tons of stuff that I would expect to receive some form of colored formatting such as function calls, function parameters etc all just appear as white text.

After looking at loads of VS Code python tutorials online, it would definitely seem something is wrong with my setup as everyone else seems to receive function calls/function paramters/etc syntax highlighting.

Troubleshooting progress so far:

- I have the VS Code python extension installed.
- I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code.
- I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python extension.
- I've tried installing the magicPython
  extension.
- Ensuring I have both python2 and python3 installed on my machine
- Color theme is currently Dark+, however this behavior occurs with all
  color themes.
- Made sure the file ends in .py

I'm running on a Mac, if that's relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you point out a specific line where you think Sublime is colouring but VS Code isn't? Otherwise everything looks to be highlighted in both files equally.

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need to change your theme
check this one out https://github.com/sobolevn/dotfiles